# почему заранее сохранённые объекты jquery нельзя использовать?

Tags: jquery

```
...
var obj_new_summ_pr = $('[name="new_summ_pr"][data-id="'+ id +'"]');
...
```

если я потом по коду пишу так:

```
obj_new_summ_pr.html(znak * confirm_count * bill_price);
```

то это не работает, а если вот так:

```
$('[name="new_summ_pr"][data-id="'+ id +'"]').html(znak * confirm_count * bill_price);
```

то работает.
Т.е. если я сохраняю результат в переменную, то я не могу им пользоваться, а если каждый раз ищу на странице этот элемент, то могу. Почему?

Comment: работает https://codepen.io/Manfrid/pen/yLJgQoL

Comment: Может у вас id ещё не доехало? Вот и не работает...

Comment: вы совершенно правы, я натупил. id не доехало

Answer (score 0):

Потому что объект-обертка jQuery содержит внутри ссылки на элементы страницы удовлетворяющие селектору и существующие на момент вызова

```
$('[name="new_summ_pr"][data-id="'+ id +'"]')
```

Очевидно, в момент выполнения

```
var obj_new_summ_pr = ...
```

этих элементов еще нет.